# c# using bitwise XOR for swapping

Tags: c#, algorithm

```
void swap(ref int x, ref int y)
{       x = x ^ y;   y = y ^ x;   x = x ^ y;  }
```

im learning about bitwise XOR. how is this swapping occurring? it's blowing my mind. this method is supposed to swap the contents of X and Y, but i dont understand AT ALL what is going on?

Comment: Write down the operations on paper with example x and y values in binary.

Comment: Keep it that way and don't use it.  Whomever will maintain your code some day won't either.  You'll find several threads under the C++ tag about it, look for downvoted ones.  Otherwise write it out with 0's and 1's to see it work.  Two bits would be enough.

Comment: This was one of the swapping tricks I learned in a first year compsci class I took for fun. I couldn't help feeling stupid while performing this most micro of micro-optimizations without any reason to do so, while the obvious alternative (temp = x; x = y; y = temp;) is a million times clearer. And probably also a million times easier for a compiler to optimize.

Comment: Try swap(ref x, ref x). Surprise! :-)

Comment: This was a common practice in HLASM applications written in the late 60s and early 70s where even mainframes had very little memory to host applications. The benefit of the XOR technique was that it used less instructions to swap registers or variables, and therefore required less space. I was the unfortunate sucker to maintain such a program until it was rewritten in COBOL for Y2K. I don't see any use for the technique in modern systems.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Beware. This method has a very very nasty property. It was used in one of the Underhanded C Contest entries. It will work happily... until one day someone tries something like swapping two array elements a[i] and a[j] without assuring that i!=j.

When both references refer to the same variable, this method zeroes it.

Comment: You are correct in principle. `Swap(ref x, ref x)` will zero out the variables `x`. In C/C++ this approach has the flaw you describe. However, in C# it is not possible to pass array elements by ref so that specific case can't actually occur.

Comment: @LBushkin: I believe you are wrong. What you cannot pass by reference is the output of indexer, so `swap(ref a[0], ref a[0])` will not compile if `a` is a `List`, but will (and will execute) if it's an array of ints.

Answer (score 6):

**Wikipedia has an excellent explanation of the [Swap-By-XOR algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm).**

The formal proof that this algorithm works is a bit involved, and requires the use of the mathematical properties of binary numbers.

But in simplified form, we can consider each bit of the binary value separate, since the XOR operation acts on each independently. As such, it's sufficient to show that this works with 1-bit values, since by induction we can demonstrate it works for any length binary value. It's quite simple to build an appropriate truth table for these operations, so I leave that out.

Swap by XOR is not the only "creative" swapping algorithm possible. A similar result can be achieved by using arithmetic operations:

```
void Swap( ref int x, ref int y )
{
  x = x + y; 
  y = x - y;
  x = x - y; 
}
```

**From a practical perspective, this is a technique that should be avoided in most cases.** As you yourself recognize, the logic of this method is not immediately obvious and it can lead to maintainability and extensibility problems ... not the least of which is the fact that `Swap( ref x, ref x )` will NOT do what the method's name implies (it will zero out the value, in fact).

Answer (score 5):

Just look at it one bit at a time and one step at a time.

```
x|y -> x = x ^ y x|y -> y = y ^ x x|y -> x = x ^ x x|y
0|0              0|0              0|0              0|0
0|1              1|1              1|0              1|0
1|0              1|0              1|1              0|1
1|1              0|1              0|1              1|1
```

Here you can clearly see that the result in each case is a swapping of the bits. From here it is clear why it works in the general case. More [formal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm) explanations are possible.

Anytime you find yourself saying "I don't understand at all what is going on" is a strong indication that you should find a clearer way to write semantically-equivalent code.

Comment: You have a typo in there, last step is x = x ^ y; but the table entries are of course correct.. :)

Answer (score 2):

swap() can be implemented with a single CPU instruction on most modern architectures (including i686 and x86_64). Hence, you are better off writing it in a way the compiler can recognize and convert accordingly rather than trying to micro optimize in a way that will actually make your code slower and less readable.

Answer (score 1):

First of all look at how XOR works:

```
a | b | a^b
- - - - - -
0 | 0 | 0
1 | 0 | 1
0 | 1 | 1
1 | 1 | 0
```

So the result of an xor operation is 1 or true if the inputs are different, and 0 if the inputs are equal. Another way to look at it is to think of it as addition without carry, i'll denote it as (+) :

```
x = x ^ y <=> x = x (+) y;
y = y ^ x <=> y = y (+) x;
x = x ^ y <=> x = x (+) y;
```

**First step**  : set all the bits that are 0 in x but 1 in y to 1. Now some bits are wrong in x because if a bit is 1 in x and also y it'll be set to 0. The other bits are correct.

**Second step** : Now set the same bit positions we set to 1 in x to 0 in y (we are done with y now). This works because x already has all bits that are different set to 1, so XORing y with x now basically means: toggle the bits in y that are set to 1 in x. We are done with y now :)

**Third step**  : now we still need to set those bits in x to 1 that already were set to 1 originally and were reset to 0 after the first step back to 1. How ? We just XOR x with y one last time because what does xor do ? it sets a bit to 1 if the 2 inputs differ, which is exactly what we need.

If you are still confused about it you should just draw it on paper and play it through to see how it works and/or refer to the tables Jason did above.